# Does a combination of lifecycleScope and SharedFlow eliminate the need for ViewModels?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I'm diving into Kotlin Flow for the first time, and I'm wondering if with it ViewModel has a place anymore.  ViewModel's advantage was that it was lifecycle aware and would automatically cancel subscriptions on the ViewModel's LiveData when the Activity gets destroyed.  A Kotlin SharedFlow works similarly to LiveData in that it can be subscribed to by multiple observers.  And in Kotlin a lifecycleScope coroutine should cancel all child coroutines upon the lifecycle ending.  So if we had something like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    //Do something
    flow.emit(result)
}

lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    flow.collect {
        //Display the data
    }
}
```

This should cancel when the lifecycle goes out of scope.  Am I missing a problem here?  Or is there a good reason to use ViewModels anyway?  Assume here that there are no 3rd party libraries I need to interact with that expect LiveData or ViewModels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping the whole discussion aside of `LiveData` vs `SharedFlow` or `StateFlow`. Coming onto `ViewModels` as you asked. If we are to go by documentation

> The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way. The ViewModel class allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations.

> UI controllers such as activities and fragments are primarily intended to display UI data, react to user actions, or handle operating system communication, such as permission requests. Requiring UI controllers to also be responsible for loading data from a database or network adds bloat to the class. Assigning excessive responsibility to UI controllers can result in a single class that tries to handle all of an app's work by itself, instead of delegating work to other classes. Assigning excessive responsibility to the UI controllers in this way also makes testing a lot harder.

> It's easier and more efficient to separate out view data ownership from UI controller logic.

I guess this sums it up quite well. It is true that `lifeCycleScope` can eliminate the need of `ViewModel` in a way, but `ViewModel` does more than just being a holder for `LiveData`.

Even if you want to use `SharedFlow` or `StateFlow` over `LiveData` I would suggest you still make use of `ViewModel` and inside it use a `viewModelScope` instead to still perform the usual and required separation of concerns between UI and data.

Comment: What more does it do?  I read what you posted and understand the architectural considerations there, but that can be done just as effectively without it.  The best argument I see for it is as an aggregator of multiple pieces of data rather than independent flows.

Comment: Handling configuration changes, Lifecycle awareness, Data sharing between activities or Fragments. For smaller projects, you're right. I hear your argument and sympathise - however there are good reasons for this, drudged and repetitive work, especially in larger and more complicated applications @GabeSechan

Comment: But being in the LifecycleScope should handle the configuration changes and lifecycle awareness (unless you need something to happen in onPause or something like that, but there's extentions for that explicitly, and its not free in ViewModel/LiveData either). Or is there something I'm missing where LifecycleScope won't handle that?

Comment: The normal `lifecycleScope` does not do that, it doesn't exactly handle configuration changes. Any coroutine launched in this scope is canceled when the Lifecycle is destroyed. But it does not restart it. To achieve that Lifecycle and LifecycleOwner provide the suspend repeatOnLifecycle API that does exactly that.

Comment: Ok, that I get.  I can see then a usecase for viewmodel holding flows (and providing aggregation, which could have been annoying), and then it becomes a flow vs livedata within the view model argument.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ViewModel survives configuration changes. Activities and Fragments do not. That’s the primary purpose of ViewModel. ViewModel does *not* automatically cancel subscriptions to its LiveData. LiveData does that for itself independently. For that reason, the existence of SharedFlow has no impact whatsoever on the usefulness of ViewModel.

If you’re following an MVVM pattern and using ViewModel as the VM, then using SharedFlow instead of LiveData takes it a step closer to being platform agnostic and being easier to unit test.